# Why does the "grammatical anaphora" do the opposite of what the "rhetorical anaphora does"?

Tags: meaning

The following 2 definitions of **anaphora** are from the **[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anaphora)**.

> 1 Grammar
>
> The use of a word referring back to a word used earlier in a text or
>   conversation, to avoid repetition, for example the pronouns he, she,
>   it, and they and the verb do in I like it and so do they.
>
> 2 Rhetoric
>
> The repetition of a word or phrase at the beginning of successive
>   clauses.

***Why does the "grammatical anaphora" do the opposite of what the "rhetorical anaphora does"?*** In other words, why does the "grammatical anaphora" avoid "a carry back" (etymological meaning of 'anaphora') when rhetorically it carries back words, phrases or clauses?

> "repetition of a word or phrase in successive clauses," 1580s, from
>   Latin, from Greek anaphora "reference," literally "a carrying back,"
>   from anapherein "to carry back, to bring up," from ana "back" (see
>   ana-) + pherein "to bear," from PIE root *bher- (1) "to carry." ([Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anaphora))

Comment: The idea that the linguistic anaphora does the opposite to the rhetorical anaphora (repetition) is not one that I share. I think it's your interpretation, or an interpretation. The anaphor in the linguistic anaphora refers back to a previous antecedent. The rhetorical anaphora refers back to previous words to reuse them.  That's another way of looking at it. They're both Greek for "carrying back".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, it's not at all uncommon for terms based on metaphors like this to have quite different meanings in different contexts.

In the second place, prepositions and prepositional affixes are notoriously flexible in meaning. Note that the Latin translation of *anaphor-*, *refer-* uses the (etymologically) identical stem, but *re-* where the Greek has *ana-*. I don't know whether *ana-* is as flexible, but *re-* can mean either *back, in the opposite direction* or *once more*—the two notions are very closely *related* (another example of *refer-*), because the motion is conceived as metaphorically cyclic.

So there's really no contradiction here: the grammatical meaning carries you back ("refers" you) to a prior instance (the "referent") to recognize its significance, and the rhetorical meaning carries you back to the previous instance of the construction to grasp its rhetorical significance.

Comment: 'Ana, conveniently for English speakers, means **again,** and **against.** So, *anamnesis,* (again) 'memory;' and *ana potamon* (against)  upstream.

Comment: As a preposition, ανα _ana_ is either distributive ('in the midst') or spatial ('up') [Daniel B Wallace _Beyond the Basics_ 1996 p364]. My understanding is that the prefix ανα, _ana_ prompts the concept of something arising ('up'). Or, as we say, 'coming up (again)'. The Greek preposition (and prefix) παλιν _palin_ is the one that bears the meaning of going over the same ground twice in different directions (as in 'palindrome'.)